# Setting PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH for 'make check' with QMake

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I have a project setup with a couple of Apps with a shared library, this is all built nicely using a SUBDIRS project, where the apps depend on the shared library.

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = app1 app2 sharedLib
app1.depends = sharedLib
app2.depends = sharedLib
```

Each app also contains a number of tests, with `CONFIG += testcase` set.

This creates a `check` target so we can run all unit test from the top level .pro using `make check`.

The problem is that some of the app tests require the presence of the code within the sharedLib, therefore it needs to be discoverable according to each platforms library lookup rules.

On Windows one option is to have the sharedLib location on the `PATH`, on linux we can add the sharedLib location to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, on mac `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

One solution is to just set the location of the built shared lib before running `make check`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:build/sharedDll/
make check
```

and this works, but it seems a little redundant as it is the build scripts themselves that are building the shared library so they know the path to the sharedLib binary location, which can be referenced from within .pro/pri files at:

```
$$TOP_BUILDDIR/sharedLib/release
```

So, is there anyway to set the `PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH/DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within the project files for the purposes of the `make check` command?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gcc, you can use rpath parameter of gcc.

> -rpath=dir
>         Add a directory to the **runtime** library search path.  This is used
>         when linking an ELF executable with shared objects.  All -rpath
>         arguments are concatenated and passed to the **runtime** linker, which
>         uses them to locate shared objects at **runtime.**

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -rpath=/the/absolute/path

If you use that technique, it will not be necessary to edit LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I check this solution and unfortunately didn't work for me, So I test `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=\\\$\/path2lib` and this method works for me, I hope this comment would enhance the answer and helps someone(before running your project make sure to clean project and re-run it)

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5.5, the following qmake statement prepends the path `$$TOP_BUILDDIR/sharedLib/release` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the target `check`:

```
check.commands = LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$$TOP_BUILDDIR/sharedLib/release:\$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH $$check.commands
```

I drew inspiration for this solution from the files `testcast.prf` and `qt_functions.prf` (especially the functions `qtAddTargetEnv()` and `qtAddToolEnv()`), both located in `$$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/mkspecs/features`.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that `qmake` has a variable for searching for libs in a custom dir, it's called `QMAKE_LIBDIR`.

Instead of manually adding a lib path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, you can set this in your .pro file, and then link the libraries you need with:
`QMAKE_LIBDIR = /path_to_your_libs`
`-L/path_to_your_libs -l<whatever_lib_you_need>`